# How to put the key and value from firebase database to hashmap?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I have this list of dataSnapshot from database

```
dataSnapshot:
"DataSnapshot { key = personTypes,
value = {RESIDENT_HOMEOWNER=Resident Homeowner, 
RESIDENT_RELATIVE=Resident Relative,
ADMIN=Admin, DRIVER_OUT=Driver Stay-out} }"
```

and from data: (database)

```
data:
"DataSnapshot { key = ADMIN,
value = Admin }"
```

my code is

```
private Map<String, String> personTypeToDisplayMap = new HashMap<>();
private Map<String, String> displayToPersonTypeMap = new HashMap<>();

public void fetchPersonTypes() {
    getDbRefKlearyan().child("personTypes").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    personTypeToDisplayMap.put(data.getKey(), data.getValue(String.class));
                    displayToPersonTypeMap.put(data.getValue(String.class), data.getKey());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

Now, my problem is i cant store any data in personTypetoDisplayMap and displayToPersonTypeMap. Everytime I debug the app, its size are always size=0.

I also tried doing `personTypeToDisplayMap.put("string", "sassy");`
for testing but the result is the same

Comment: The size for `personTypeToDisplayMap` and `displayToPersonTypeMap` are zero even if you verify this inside the `onDataChange()` method?

Comment: @AlexMamo what do you mean by verifying it inside onDataChange()? It's visibly inside the onDataChange method

Comment: Check the size of those maps right after the for loops ends. If you are checking there the size is true that it isn't zero, right?

Comment: oh okay, thank you! @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use something now, that hasn't been loaded yet. With other words, you cannot simply use the `personTypeToDisplayMap` and `displayToPersonTypeMap` maps outside the `onDataChange()` method because it will always have the size of `zero` due the asynchronous behaviour of this method. This means that by the time you are trying to use those maps outside that method, the data hasn't finished loading yet from the database and that's why is not accessible.

A quick solve for this problem would be to use the both maps only inside the `onDataChange()` method, otherwise I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.